# Check if key exists without touching disks

Tags: cassandra

We're hitting IO limit with our Cassandra setup. I wonder if there is a way to check if certain key exists without touching disks. I'm aware of [key cache](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsConfiguringCaches.html#Aboutthepartitionkeycache) but the memory usage is quite a lot for us. Also, I learned that Cassandra uses [bloom filters](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuningBloomFilters.html) for index scans. Is there a way to test key existence with the internal setup of Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are talking about for index scans. The keycache if filled will tell you for certain if a key exists on disk though.

Each sstable has a bloom filter thats in memory and some metadata that can help but cannot guarantee it. The bloom filter will tell you for sure if it does not exist, but may give a false positive. There are stats for this you can check and you can set the false positive percentage goal. Also each sstable has a min/max token and min/max clustering key which if your key does not exist in it can also exclude it from being possible.

Unfortunately you cannot execute this without actually doing the read, so once it finds an sstable it will attempt to read from it. You can do a `LIMIT 1` to at least minimize that though. You could also put in your application a cache of keys you know do or do not exist if your ok with it being potentially out of sync. And some mechanism to evict them when added or removed.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking about, but I seems a bit not-so-clean to me if I implement another caching layer when Cassandra already implemented a bunch of them.

Comment: There will likely be a systen_view option in the future that can provide this but thats a few versions away.